# Can't override java.util.logging.LogManager in a Spring Boot web application: Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on already loaded class

Tags: spring-boot, java.util.logging

I am trying to override `java.util.logging.LogManager` with my own configuration:

**class CloudwatchHandler** is an implementation of `Handler` and includes this `init()` method:

```
public static void init() {
    final String julConfigFile = System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.file");
    if(julConfigFile != null) {
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(julConfigFile)) {
            LogManager logManager = LogManager.getLogManager();
            logManager.reset();
            logManager.readConfiguration(is);
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CloudwatchHandler.class.getName());
            logger.info("LOADED");
        } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
            System.err.println(Instant.now() + ": Failed to initialize JUL.");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.err.println(Instant.now() + ": java.util.logging.config.file was not specified");
    }

}
```

Application main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CloudwatchHandler.init();
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
}
```

Error

```
Can't load log handler "mypackage.CloudwatchHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.CloudwatchHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypackage.CloudwatchHandler
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.createLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:1005)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(LogManager.java:975)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$4.run(LogManager.java:971)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:971)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java:2424)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.accessCheckedHandlers(LogManager.java:2526)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.getHandlers(Logger.java:2090)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:977)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:1007)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:1030)
        at java.logging/java.util.logging.Logger.info(Logger.java:1803)
        at mypackage.CloudwatchHandler.init(CloudwatchHandler.java:51)
        ... main ...
```

The really crazy thing about this exception is that the class causing the `ClassNotFoundException` is actually a caller in the current stack frame, as seen in the stack trace. So clearly it has been FOUND or it couldn't be running.

What's causing this and how can I fix it? I just want to load my own log handler.

Spring Boot version is 2.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassNotFoundException can occur if the Handler is not deployed to load in the [system class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()) as that is what the LogManager uses to find handlers.

Update your test case and try again:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    System.out.println(CloudwatchHandler.class.getClassLoader());

    //This is what CloudwatchHandler.init(); triggers
    Class.forName(CloudwatchHandler.class.getName(), true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

   //This is what the LogManager is doing
   Class.forName(CloudwatchHandler.class.getName(), true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());


   //Force load the root handlers.
   Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers();

   CloudwatchHandler.init();
   SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
}
```

If it is that the handler is deployed in the context class loader and not in the system classloader then you need to change how you package the handler so it is visible to the system classloader.  The `java.util.logging.config.class` option is one part of the LogManager that will try loading classes via context classloader which is what will be able to see your classes.  For this option you move the contents of your init method to a new class and have the constructor perform the action.  On the command line then set the value to the FQCN of the new config class.

Comment: I think you are right. The system class loader doesn't look inside `BOOT-INF`. I have a new question now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71990302/how-can-i-tell-spring-boot-to-place-some-of-the-classes-at-the-root-of-the-jar-i?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @AlexR Since you already have an init method as opposed to all configuration file code, you could simply remove the line from the configuration file that is adding the handler to code using Logger::addHandler.  You just have to move your init code so it is called from the SpringApplication class loader.

Comment: removing the class from the config file and calling `Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(new CloudwatchHandler());` in my init method and then calling that from `main()` works! And I understand why it works. However, somewhat miraculously, calling init via a constructor specified in `java.util.logging.config.class` also works! I don't understand why the latter approach works. It should give me NoClassDefErrors on the logger's dependencies.

Comment: `java.util.logging.config.class` works because in the source code of LogManager that is the only path which tries the context classloader and the system classloader.