# How can I tell Spring Boot to place some of the classes at the root of the jar instead of BOOT-INF?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, classloader, java.util.logging

I'm trying to set a custom log `Handler` in my Spring Boot (version 2.6.3) application. The result is a `ClassNotFound` as described in this other question

> [Can't override java.util.logging.LogManager in a Spring Boot web application: Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on already loaded class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71985174/cant-override-java-util-logging-logmanager-in-a-spring-boot-web-application-ge/71990159#71990159)

Based on the answer to that question, it seems I need my `Handler` and all its dependencies to be placed into the root of the executable jar.

Is there a direct way to accomplish this during the Maven build, i.e. not by extracting and repackaging the jar myself post-build?

Comment: A spring boot application has a particular setup which means the classes have been in particular places because that's how spring boot works (There is a startup parts and the part which is in BOOT-INF... Furthermore what kind of Handler do you need to define in a spring boot app ?

Comment: The question can be rephrased as "how do I tell Spring Boot to place some of my classes in the startup parts of the executable jar?". My handler sends log events to a proprietary service.

Comment: Why do you need to put that into the startup ? What not using the usual application events of Spring Boot? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-repackage

Comment: @khmarbaise "Why do you need to put that into the startup?" is explained in my question: I need to do that in order to resolve a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: That is not the reason. Why does something used in Spring need to be put into the startup..all the startup events etc. can be used...and using a log handler even more?

Comment: There are some suggestions in [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6626).

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thanks for the link, that leads to a wealth of information

Comment: @khmarbaise I am not sure if you are saying "it should work", well, it doesn't, please review the linked Spring Boot issues and you'll see I'm not the only one experiencing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is a result of BOOT-INF fat jar structure introduced by Spring Boot 1.4.

There is currently no straightforward solution, and it appears some of the Spring Boot maintainers do not agree there is a problem, so it could be a long time before the situation changes:

- Issue #6626: [Make it easier to package certain content in the root of a fat jar](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6626)
- Issue #12659: [Starting executable war with -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager produces a ClassNotFoundException](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12659)

**WORKAROUND #1**

I had to do two things to get my application working again with a custom log handler. 1) use Maven Shade to package up the log handler with all its dependencies, and 2) launch the app with using the `PropertiesLauncher` class in the command line instead of using `java -jar`:

```
java -cp executable.jar:logger-shaded.jar -Dloader.main=mypackage.myapp org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

The `executable.jar`, `logger-shaded.jar`, and `mypackage.myapp` are placeholders specific to my project, so adjust accordingly.

**WORKAROUND #2**

If the handler is loaded from code in a config class or from `main()` instead of being specified in the file loaded via `java.util.logging.config.file`, as discussed in the comments to the answer in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71985174/cant-override-java-util-logging-logmanager-in-a-spring-boot-web-application-ge?noredirect=1&lq=1), then everything works as expected. I actually prefer this over Workaround #1 as it results in a smaller deployment, but it does require writing a few more lines of code.